# Hamburger Menu is not opening on my webpage while using bootstrap. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

My navbar hamburger menu is not opening and I have no clue why? The links show fine on a big screen but the navbar wont open on a smaller screen. I have tried changing the tags in the header and deleting things and refreshing the page to figure out the issue but nothing works. I am new to Bootstrap and Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" 
     crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Megan-Keyes</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "header-my-name">
        <header><h2>Hi</h2></header>
            </div>
       <button class="navbar-toggler"type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
data-bs-target=#navmenu>
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="Currency-Converter/index.html" class="nav-link" target="projectWindow1">Currency Converter</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="Famous-Landmarks/index.html" class="nav-link">Famous Landmarks</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="project-3" class="nav-link">Project 3</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="project-4" class="nav-link">Project 4</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="project-5" class="nav-link">Project 5</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="project-6" class="nav-link">Project 6</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="project-7" class="nav-link">Project 7</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="project-8" class="nav-link">Project 8</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <!--NavBar Color and text center-->
   <section class="bg-dark text-light p-5 text-center"> 
   </section>
   <!--My Project Displays-->
   <main>
    <div id = "currency-converter-project">
    <iframe src="Currency-Converter/index.html" name="projectWindow1" width="100%" height="100px"></iframe> 
    </div>
    <div id = "famous-landmarks-project">
    <iframe src="Famous-Landmarks/index.html" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe> 
    </div>
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors if you open the console panel in your browser’s dev tools?

Comment: Please put it in a code snippet so that we know what is the problem.

Comment: I feel you are using the wrong version of Boostrap. Your CSS, Js imports is of ver. 3.4.1 but your HTML (markup) is from version 5. The selectors which Bootstrap.js wants don't meet.

Use one version, don't mix two.

Comment: It says Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND style.css :1

Comment: also says this Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND script.js :1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link bootstrap javascript file `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: should I replace this link somewhere?